# Is there a function to get wp menu in an object or array?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to build a custom menu structure so the question as per title is: Is there a native wp function or something not from wp core to get the menu in a data structure as an object or an array ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Retrieving a list of menu items in an array https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/111060/retrieving-a-list-of-menu-items-in-an-array

Comment: @RyanAW yes this solved my question

Answer (score 0):

add this on your function

```
function wp_get_menu_array($current_menu) {
    $menu_name = $current_menu;
    $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_name ] );
    $array_menu = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu->term_id); 
    $menu = array();
    foreach ($array_menu as $m) {
        if (empty($m->menu_item_parent)) {
            $menu[$m->ID] = array();
            $menu[$m->ID]['ID']      =   $m->ID;
            $menu[$m->ID]['title']       =   $m->title;
            $menu[$m->ID]['url']         =   $m->url;
            $menu[$m->ID]['children']    =   array();
        }
    }
    $submenu = array();
    foreach ($array_menu as $m) {
        if ($m->menu_item_parent) {
            $submenu[$m->ID] = array();
            $submenu[$m->ID]['ID']       =   $m->ID;
            $submenu[$m->ID]['title']    =   $m->title;
            $submenu[$m->ID]['url']  =   $m->url;
            $menu[$m->menu_item_parent]['children'][$m->ID] = $submenu[$m->ID];
        }
    }
    return $menu;
}
```

and retrieve the array on your view by

```
wp_get_menu_array('your_menu_name');
```